# Floyd Triangle with loop forward & backward

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi i want to know to make a floyd triangle with loop forward and backward in python?

```
floyd triangle code
   
    n = 5
    num = 1

    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i+1):
            print(num, end=" ")
            num = num+1
        print()
```

and output

```
1
2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15
```

my expected output

```
1
2 3
4 5 4
3 2 1 2
```

row limit is 5 and when looping 1-5 is reverse to 5-1 after reverse loop going forward loop again

Comment: Your code looks misformatted. There are some missing indents, so the code will not run at all

Comment: @arseny it fixed

Comment: So you have as input `n`. What is the input for the "row limit"? Do you have a variable for it? It seems you have not tried to implement this reversal at all? What is the problem you have when trying?

Comment: Consider having a `direction` variable that starts out set to 1.  When you reach your limit, change `direction = -direction`.

Comment: @TimRoberts i will try it